# How to manage session in strophe for multi tab?

Tags: xmpp, strophe.js

I am creating chat system with strophe js.But I am facing issue with multi tabs.

It is really big deal in system.I found so many posts in stackoverflow and other sites also.

But not correct answer or ponding for answers.

Is it really big deal?

Please provide some solution.

Thankyou

Comment: Anyone please help on it?

Comment: Anyone have solution?